# Макросы в #pragma

Tags: c++, visual-c++, макросы

Есть библиотека, которая компилируется под разные версии Visual C++ в разных режимах - динамическая, статическая, 64 и 32 разряда.

Имя самого файла имеет вид

```
lib@####$$

@    - в случае динамической библиотеки равно d (можно привязать к опции /MD), 
       иначе отсутствует
#### - версия компилятора, что в макросе _MSC_VER
$$   - 64, если макрос _WIN64 равен 1, иначе отсутствует
```

А теперь сам вопрос - я хочу написать конструкцию, которая бы сама включала нужную мне библиотеку. Я могу взять, например

```
#pragma comment(lib, "lib180064")
```

Но это для конкретного сочетания. Для произвольной библиотеки и вариантов компиляции можно расписать сложную ветвящуюся структуру из `#if` и `#else`, но хочется сделать проще, особенно с учетом того, что для новой версии и нового `_MSC_VER` опять ветвить придется.

Это можно как-то упростить? Собирать этот `#pragma comment` в зависимости от того, чем компилирую? Я никак сообразить не могу.

Comment: Вариант, прописывать нужные либы в свойства проекта, рассматривали? (без #pragma comment lib)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Это еще более скучно. Тем более что я часто работаю просто в командной строке. А это позволило бы перекомпилировать проект, скажем, для другой разрядности, ничего не меняя в нем.

Comment: Сохраняя параметры сборки в настройках проекта можно без проблем пересобирать его из командной строки для другой разрядности ничего не меняя в нем. А  pragma lib - это нестандартное расширение языка, так что когда будете портировать на другие платформы все равно придется переделывать.

Comment: @VTT Ну нет у меня проекта, только makefile...

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. `#pragma comment(lib)` принимает строку, можно её собрать в зависимости от условий:

```
#define STRING2(x) #x
#define STRING(x) STRING2(x)

#ifdef _WIN64
#define LIB_64 "64"
#else
#define LIB_64 ""
#endif

#ifdef _DLL
#define LIB_DLL "@"
#else
#define LIB_DLL ""
#endif

#pragma comment(lib, "lib" LIB_DLL STRING(_MSC_VER) LIB_64 ".lib")
```

Comment: Нет, жаль, но получается что-то типа `#pragma comment(lib, "lib" "1912" ".lib")` - и компилятор это в одну строку не собирает. Видимо, в коде это сработает, но не здесь.

Comment: В VS2017 собирает в одну строку, а у вас какая версия?

Comment: Она самая. Еще раз - это собирается в коде, если бы это было в `cout` - это бы сработало, но в `#pragma` это не работает, я проверил...

Comment: Странно, проверил у себя - подключается нормально. Что если сначала подключить библиотеку просто подставив ожидаемое имя  в #pragma. Затем попробовать разбить его на две части в кавычках?

Comment: Совсем запутался. Если разрезаю сам - работает, если собираю как вы написали - не работает. Завтра на свежую голову посмотрю...

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в лог строку, поставив вместо `#pragma comment`, [`#pragma message()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dkzch2.aspx)